# How to receive a type that extends an interface without losing the original type

Tags: f#

I have just started using F# and my brain is broken trying to figure out how to work with its types without having to resort to an OO type of programming.

Here is my situation I basically want to create a method where I provide the type and the Id and it returns to me the object on the database.

So basically this is what I get so far.

```
let client = MongoClient()
let database = client.GetDatabase("testdb")

let lowerCase (str : string) = 
    str.ToLower()

let nameOf (classType: Type) = 
    classType.Name

let nameTypeOf<'a> = 
    nameOf typeof<'a>   

let getCollection<'a> =
    let collectionName = nameTypeOf<'a> |> lowerCase
    database.GetCollection<'a> collectionName

let dbSelect<'a> id = 
    let collection = getCollection<'a>
    collection.Find(fun(x) -> x.Id = id).First()
```

So my problem is with the dbSelect, obviously it does not compile since x is generic, basically I wanted to create an interface with the Id and all my objects interface with it.
I do know how to do it using classes and inheritances, but I am avoiding having to use instanced classes outside interop with c# libraries. What would be the best functional way to do it, if there is any.

This is what I was eexpecting to call it with

```
type IDbObject = 
    abstract Id: string

type Item = 
    {
        Id: string
        Name: string
    }
    interface IDbObject with
        member x.Id = x.Id

let item = 
    selectDb<Item> "5993592a35ce962b80da1e22"
```

Any help would be appreciated.
And if anyone want to point out how crappy my code is, any feedback is really appreciated

Comment: You can use type constraints to better specify what `'a` needs to be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints

Comment: Do not drive yourself into a corner assuming that "plain-old" classes are somehow secondary citizens in the F# world. It's easy to get such an impression when just getting into the language, but limiting yourself to "native F# types" is just that - limiting yourself.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev it was that the exact problem that I was having thank you for the documentation.

Comment: @scrwtp I am using this project to force myself to use the minimum amount of the OO just to get more used to thinking functional, that being said your feedback is really important and I will take it into account while programing :) thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @Destino Sure, have fun. Just saying since it's a pattern I happen to see too often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the solution here is much different from what you'd have in C#. You can constrain the generic type to use the interface members, getting something roughly like this:

```
let getCollection<'a when 'a :> IDbObject> () =
   let collectionName = nameTypeOf<'a> |> lowerCase
   database.GetCollection<'a> collectionName

let dbSelect<'a when 'a :> IDbObject> id =
   let collection = getCollection<'a>()
   collection.Find(fun (x : 'a) -> x.Id = id).First()
```

The type of `dbSelect` should be inferred to be `string -> #IDbObject`, and be coerced to `string -> 'a` at the call site.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.
I did not know about type constraint, it was kinda overlooked on the tutorial i was following thats why I was stuck.
You just saved me.